# Karate - retry until for all httpcall

Tags: karate

Our servers are not really stable, sometimes I receive Internal Server Error 500. `retry until` is really good way to bypass the issue but I have to put it above every method action.

My idea is to use `afterHttpCall` hook to retry the http call if status code is 500, but I have no idea how to rerun the step in this hook.
Does anyone know how to overcome this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the hook is not designed for re-running a step. Since this request has never come up before, you should consider contributing code to Karate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've come up with beforeStep hook. I check if `step.getText().startsWith("method")` then `sr.evalAsStep("retry until responseStatus != 500");`